# updating year field in date or Converting varchar to date

Tags: sql, date, casting, sql-update

[image]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have used cast,replace.they are not working. please assist.

attached in the screenshot

I need to update year value in date field.

Comment: Please post code as (formatted) text, not as image. An image can't be searched, can't be copied as code

Comment: exactly what are you doing on Birthdate in temp table part,

Comment: Btw, `!= null` is not going to work, the correct way to check for NULL is `IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Depending, which sql you are using:
e.g.

[mysql](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/changing-year-in-mysql-date)

[ms sql](https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2018/09/06/t-sql-date-and-time-manipulation/) (use format, and replace yyyy with year of your choice)

[postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html) (e.g. makedate(yyyy, extract(month from birthdate), extract(day from birthdate))